# Ajax selected dropdown value and pass

Tags: django, ajax, jinja2, dropdown

I am trying to do following: user will select the value from the drop down menu, I would like to capture the data and pass to value to check if it exits and filter it.

Using django view to fetch the media data files list. I would like to filter base on selected data site.

VIEW

```
@ajax_request
def listofiles(request, *args, **kwargs):
    dir_name = "configurations"
    template_name = 'loadlistofiles.html'
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, dir_name)
    filelist = []
    context = {'file': filelist}

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith(".pdf"): # to avoid other files
            filelist.append("{}{}/{}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, dir_name, f))
    return render(request, template_name, {'file': filelist})
```

Above code will provide the list of all the files. I would like to filter it down using the dropdown select

HTML AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#files").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({
            url: 'loadlistofiles.html',
            type: $(this).attr('GET'),
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                $("#fetchdata").html(data); // update the DIV
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How to filter based on dropdown select value and check if the string in the file. 
For example:
File name: `dublin.aus1.pdf`
Dropdown will have a list like: AUS1, CH1, IND1
Like to check if the `aus1` is in the file, if so only print display.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a GET parameter in your url. Then, in your view, you would filter based on that parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to Fetch the data from the selected dropdown and able to filter it.